# Add external files (.css, .js, ecc) in rest application jax-rs, maven project

Tags: java, css, rest, maven, jax-rs

Good morning, 
i am creating a **REST** application with **JAX-RS** and i'm using **maven**. Unfortunately I didn't understand as well the other question about this topic.

I created a .css file that i have to link for the output of my web application. for the html part, i didn't write "pure" html code, but i'm using *RenderSnake* API and when i try to add external css i don't understan whit path i have to add.

Can anyone explain me in which folder i have to add my files?
Do I add something into the pom.xml file?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you building a `war` or a `jar`?

Answer (score -1):

typically you would add those fines (.html, .css and so on) in `/src/main/webapp` or some sub folder (in your case `/src/main/webapp/assets/stylesheets`), and then reference the css in the .html file using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css">
```

or something similar (notice the missing heading `/` in the path, which makes the path relative to the html file).
For this to work, you'll have to put the .html file in `/src/main/webapp/`.
If you comply with Maven conventions about resource placement, then when you package the web application Maven will take care of those files for you.

EDIT :
as per [rendersnake examples page ('include static content' section)](http://rendersnake.org/examples.html), just use a `Renderable` :

```
public class CssRenderable implements Renderable {

  public void renderOn(HtmlCanvas html) throws IOException {
    String host = RequestUtils.getHeaderValue(html, "HOST");
    if(host.startsWith("localhost"))
        return;
    html.write(StringResource.get("assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css"),NO_ESCAPE);      
  }
}
```

(of course, this is taken from the example page, change it as you need).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to do that: I created a folder called assets, with a subfolder called stylesheets and i put there the file mystyle.css. When i execute my application, in the source code of the page i see '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css">' but the resource is not found, error 404: I see thet in the inspector. I don't know why that resource is not found.

Comment: **This will not work**. `href="/css/mystyle.css"` assumes the application is at the **server root** which it is likely not. You need to use your templating engine to provide the appropriate context path.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are right, better without the heading `/`, although you'll have to take into account the relative path between the html and css files. Not a problem, really.

Comment: The relative path only works if the files referencing the CSS are in the application root. If you were to use this from `http://server.com/context/admin/main.jsp` for example, it would assume you meant `http://server.com/context/admin/css/mystyle.css` - which would not work either. As I said, you need to use the appropriate directive in your template to generate an absolute path including the context - for example [`<c:url>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know, see the edit. Anyway, in this case you can use paths like you would do on any filesystem, e.g. if you  put the html files in `/src/main/webapp/html`, you would then reference the stylesheets with `../css/my.css`

Comment: Of course you _can_ do this, and have a subtly difference reference in every page that breaks whenever you refactor. But this is terrible advice. It comes from the days of CGI applications and static HTML pages. In a modern Java web application you should not be doing this and recommending it as an answer to a beginner is not wise.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't want to start a discussion here, but I don't agree with you. Since he didn't specify which technology he'll be using to write the GUI, I gave an answer that is not technically incorrect and general purpose. You imply he'll be using a templating engine, but since he's using jax-rs he may use pure js+html+css as well. For the refactoring objection, well you're right, but as an example I currently use GWT for GUIs, and the GWT template uses the accepted convention of putting html files in the webapp root and referencing the css with a relative path. I hardly ever touch it.

Comment: Everything you said it's interessant for me and now i try to explain better the situation: i wrote the server in Java, with JAX-RS; the client side is also in java, but i don't use the tag  `<html><head>`ecc, but i used RenderSnake [http://rendersnake.org/index.html], so i use java methods to create the html. Now, i run the application at localhost, but, as I said before, I can't retrive css files and the server returns me `404 Not Found`. I hope it's all clear now and thanks for your previous answers

Comment: He did say _i'm using RenderSnake API_. I use GWT too, like many people I use a JSP for the GWT template and place my GWT application wherever I like during the Maven build - the example given with a pure HTML page is only for the must basic applications and basically useless for anything more complex. GWT do in fact recommend using JSP for the bootstrap.